# Recommended way to save/tamper-proof sensitive data an app's lifetime

Tags: c#, .net, security, c#-4.0, hash

My application stores user interactions in an encrypted file that it gathers during what I can a `Session`. A session is like an offline exam so not only do we store the answers but also the mouse clicks, screen shots, etc.

A session has to remain ATOMIC so I keep saving incremental files and patch them up together at the end of the session. If the app finds traces of tampered files, it marks the session as disqualified.

What I want to achieve:

- The created incremental files only to be accessible by the application. In other words, no one with even elevated privileges should be able to modify or delete them.
- A non-Windows dependent way for the application to ensure that no one has tampered with the incremental files when a session is being packaged up.
- Memory tamper-proofing. In other words, if memory data has been modified by force, my app should get to know about it. Is this possible?

I have thought about IsolatedStorage, hashing, etc. but wanted advice from others who have done this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [SecureString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring.aspx) to store sensitive information, but only in memory. And avoid memory dump.

You can encrypt the files to avoid sensitive information to be saw in filesystem.

You can't avoid file deletion, you can lock the files for the lifetime of your application, but this ins't *bulletproof*.

Answer (score 1):

Especially with a managed environment such as .NET (and Java), there is no way of doing this safely while running on the same machine as a user that has full control over his system. Try moving the parts of the application that need to be secure to a central machine (web service for instance). This way nobody can attach a debugging tool to that logic or make a memory dump. This is the only way of securing your application.